# How to: Deploy / Run website project on Apache web server?

Tags: c#, apache, visual-studio-2012, webserver

I want to run or deploy my website on Apache server.
Does anyone have a tutorial or know of a tutorial to kindly share please. I am unable to find one on Google (believe it or not).

-Using Visual Studio 2012 / C# / SQL Server / regular webform not an MVC application

-Have Apache correctly installed on my pc

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do it, you need to create an empty ASP.NET website project in Visual Studio (File->New Web Site…) and then include all the HTML/JS files.

1. Right click on the website Project, select “Publish Web Site”.
2. Drop down the Publish Profile drop down and select New Profile. Name it “FTP” or whatever you want to call it.
3. On the Connection Tab set Publish method to FTP, fill in FTP server, root folder for the website on the server, user name and password.
4. Click “Validate” to see if we can connect.
5. Press the “Publish” button

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/07/23/publish-html-js-website-to-linux-apache-using-visual-studio.aspx

Comment: thanks I will test this as soon I get VS up and running again.

Comment: using this method to publish the project  is there anyway to enable debugging
or is there any other way to debug c# web project under apache ?